# I want to move a cursor to below a specific table in word using vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create a section below a specific table. The cursor position is in the top of the table after a specific operation.I want the cursor position below the table.

I have tried with InsertAfter the text object.It pasted in the last column of the table.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried ? What do you mean by top of the Table ? Is it before the Table or In the 1st cell of the Table ? A Screenshot might help in identifying.

Comment: It is the in the second column of first row  of the cell

Comment: Anu, normally no one should write an answer to a question that contains insufficient information. Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help] to better understand how to ask questions effectively. You should always include the code you've tried. Technically, this is "too broad". Also, if you describe the exact problem you're trying to solve you might get more information on how to solve them efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will follow your guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try the Line:**

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count
```

**Explanation** : So we are moving down the lines, as you said that your code leaves the cursor on 1st row of the table, we are moving down the number of lines equal to the number of rows in that table.

Comment: Whether this code will bring the cursor to out of the table or to end of the table itself??

Comment: Thank you it worked for me. But in my case there are many table consecutively presented. Cursor is coming out of all tables in document.I want cursor to be out of one specific table.How it to do it.Sorry I am a beginner so that asking each step.

Comment: Maybe you are mistaking it for many consecutive tables. Because the line `Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count` will count the number of rows in the table the cursor is currently at. Accept the answer and upvote if it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to get "outside" a table is to "collapse" the Range or Selection, rather than trying to move row-by-row. Also, for something like this, it may be important to check whether the selection is actually *in* a table.

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
If Selection.information(wdWithinTable) Then
  Set rng = Selection.Tables(1).Range
  rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rng.Select
End If
```